# SQL : need assistance writing query that will display if the person has anyone with a lower job position

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying write a query that will display if the person has anyone with a lower job position

```
SELECT Count(job)
FROM emp 
GROUP BY job
HAVING job < 'MANAGER';
```

Would anyone be kind enough to help me with this?

Cheers

-Jay

Answer to my question should be:

```
Number of subORD
---------------------                                                           
                    6
```

Comment: How do you determine which positions are subordinate to others?  Is there some sort of a `level` field in your database?

Comment: We need to see what your table structure looks like.

Comment: @DylanSmith - Sorry guys I added more information in the queston

Comment: hold on let me upload some tables.

Comment: How do we use the SALGRADE table to determine if somebody has any subordinates?  If their grade is greater than some number does that mean they have subordinates?

Comment: @DylanSmith - Hi dylan I have uploaded the tables, I am confused about the same thing. How can we determine the number of subordinates.

Comment: @Jay: Well you need to provide the logic to determines who is a subordinate.  If you were doing this by hand for, say `JONES`, what would the answer be?  How would you get there?  If you can describe an algorithm, we can help you turn it into a query.

Comment: So subordinates means someone with a lower position so for that JONES would have to be a boss.

Comment: So we can have something like :

emp employee, emp boss

Comment: I added the answer at the bottom.

Comment: I just dont know how to get the condition.

Comment: No, the question is not made up. These are some exercises given to us by our lecturer to practice SQL on. He has provided us with the answers too.

Comment: Is this correct: An employee A is a subordinate of employee B if B.`super` = A.`Empno`, according to your data.  That's the kind of definition we need.

Comment: @mellamokb Yes thats correct. so employee.super is the boss's empno and boss.empno is the boss's empno so you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
SELECT Super
FROM Emp 
GROUP BY Super
HAVING Super IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know the President doesn't count. Try the revised version. It is just a simpler version of Dylan's.

Comment: What answer is it returning? If it is still returning 7, then change the HAVING clause to: IS NOT NULL.

Comment: Hah.. then we finally arrive at a revised version of Dylan's.. You can't use 'WHERE' on aggregates.

Comment: Thanks for spending a lot of time on this guys! works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
Select count(*) as Supers
FROM (
Select distinct e1.EmpNo
from Emp e1 join Emp e2 on e1.EmpNo = e2.Super)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you can determine if employee A has subordinates by checking if any other employees include his ID as their "SUPER".

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
SELECT Super
FROM Emp
WHERE Super > 0
GROUP BY Super) AS Supervisors
```

Comment: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 6 Column: 21

Comment: try it now (removed the having clause).  That would work in SQL Server, been too long since I've done Oracle, but I believe it's valid ANSI SQL so I would expect it to work even in Oracle...

Comment: try getting rid of the "AS Supervisors" at the end, maybe Oracle doesn't like that particular syntax